# Spring Data Rest Endpoints Disappear After A While

Tags: spring-data-rest

I noticed that in my apps endpoints just disappear after a while without any information on why. Example: I started the application last night, this morning I curl the endpoint and get

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8081
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like after I restarted the service:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8081
{
  "_links" : {
    "roleAssignments" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/roleAssignments"
    },
    "invitations" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/invitations"
    },
    "tenantProfiles" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/tenantProfiles"
    },
    "roles" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/roles"
    },
    "companies" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/companies"
    },
    "permissions" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/permissions"
    },
    "accounts" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/accounts"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

It is super hard to reproduce reliably. Mostly, by waiting a longer period I was able to see this behavior again. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having trouble with this too and eventually came across https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1505 which describes the issue. It's been fixed in the latest version of springboot (2.2.7) so hopefully updating to that will fix your issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for that link! I'll try upgrading - hopefully that'll do the trick